# NSPopUpButtonCell indexOfSelectedItem always returns 0

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nspopupbuttoncell

I have a NSTableView with each cell containing a `NSPopUpButtonCell`. I have set the `NSPopUpButtonCell` 's action to a method that simply checks for the selected index (so that this can be saved and the table reloaded).

```
thePopUpButtonCell.action = @selector(popUpChangedValue);

-(void)popUpChangedValue {

    NSLog(@"%ld", [thePopUpButtonCell indexOfSelectedItem]);

}
```

No matter what I select, it says that the selected index is 0, even though it is not. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: What is thePopUpButtonCell? Is that an IBOutlet connected to the cell in IB?

Comment: This isn't the way you do this in a table.  If you log thePopUpButtonCell, you will see that it returns the same instance no matter which row you click on.

Comment: @rdelmar What would you suggest I do instead? How should I tell between the pop up buttons in each of the cells? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is with bindings. You would need a field in your array (a key value pair in an NSDictionary) to hold the value of the popup's selection.  In IB you would have an array controller whose content array was bound to your array (that includes the dictionary I mentioned above). The column with the popup would have its Selected Value bound to the array controller's arrangedObjects with a model key path of the key name in your dictionary.  When you change the selection in the popup, the array's value will be updated through the magic of bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `thePopUpButtonCell` is perhaps also nil? Some problem with retaining etc. perhaps.

Comment: I linked it to a NSPopUpButtonCell in the XIB file. Outputting it shows `<NSPopUpButtonCell: 0x100536760>`. `NSLog(@"%@", thePopUpButtonCell);` Do you have any other ideas?